# Grouping listitems and nesting based on classnames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, dom

I've got an unordered list that spits out as shown below (with class names allowing for CSS styling):

```
<ul>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-02"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
      <li class="level-01"> </li>
    </ul>
```

I've been asked to change the way this works - the `level-02` list-items need to be nested inside the "parent" `level-01`. (the `level-01` list-items contain a checkbox which if check would show it's nested options)

Basically I'm in need of a script that adds each `level-02` 'li-item' inside the closest `level-01`. But I can't seem to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: Which `level-02` items should go under which `level-01` items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `li`s and append the `2`s to the `1`s - see demo below:

```js
var list = $('<ul/>'), prev, parent;

$('ul li').each(function(){
  // add to list if level 1
  if($(this).hasClass('level-01')) {
    list.append(this);
    // save the current level 1
    prev = $(this);
    parent = null;
  } else {
    // create a sub-list ul
    if(!parent) {
       prev.append($('<ul/>'));
       parent = prev.find('ul');
    }
    // append to the sub-list
    parent.append($(this));
  }
});

$('body').append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
</ul>
```

A simpler solution that finds the nearest *level 1* element:

```js
$('.level-02').each(function(){
  var parent = $(this).prev('.level-01');
  if(!parent.find('ul').length)
    parent.append($('<ul/>'));
  parent.find('ul').append(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-02"> 2</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
  <li class="level-01"> 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prev()` method in jquery to append it to the previous `.level-01` like this

```
$('.level-02').each(function(){
    var nearest = $(this).prev('.level-01');
  nearest.append($(this));
})
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I believe your answer will indeed insert the level-02's into the 'previous' level-01. I'll keep you updated when I get to work.